# Adding another website on your hosting, Godaddy

Tags: web, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

the company i worked in purchased a web hosting from GoDaddy which is a Linux based hosting using Cpanel. I believe it is unlimited websites. Supposed it is already hosting `sample.com` which I deployed, it is a laravel 5 website. Then I want to add new website `sample2.com` which a domain the we already purchased.

On the cpanel there's an option of `Addon Domains` so I tried it out. I was able to add `sample2.com` and as expected it's root directory will be shared to `sample.com`

but when I browse to `sample2.com` I get `Internal Server Error 500` plus in the url it is poiting to `sample2.com/sample2.com` which I believe it is appending the folder on the url? What could be the problem? Is there other configuration I missed? Both my hosting and domain names came from GoDaddy.

```
public_html/
  sample2.com/
(sample.com files)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out my problem. It is my Laravel 5 .htaccess on my `public_html` folder. I just rename it to something else and my second website works then rename it again to its original then all sites works fine.